# Is there a way to add subviews to Xcode without reseting the position of the last view added?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, addsubview

This is my code:

```
let newView = ImageView()
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newView.backgroundColor = .random()
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    let panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    panGR.delegate = self
    newView.addGestureRecognizer(panGR)

    let pinchGR = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(pinch:)))
    pinchGR.delegate = self
    newView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGR)

    let rotateGR = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotate(rotate:)))
    rotateGR.delegate = self
    newView.addGestureRecognizer(rotateGR)
```

Every time the button is pressed, it runs this code. However, all of the subviews keep reseting their position.

This is the code for 'handlePan':

```
@objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code in `handlePan`?

Comment: You should post the code for your other gesture recognizer action methods as well.

Comment: I added it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set a constraints at custom view creating.

After custom view was added to superview, you change its position by dragging - but you do it just change `center` property. Ok.

When you did added new custom view to your superview - will be executed layout subviews. And all your subviews positions will be reseted according initial constraints.

You need:

- Either do not use constraints in your subviews
- Either In your `handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer)` func change 
  `centerXAnchor,centerYAnchor` constraint values, not center property. Because after any layout subviews, their positions will be set to original.

  ```
  let newView = UIImageView.init(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
  newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  newView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
  view.addSubview(newView)

  // newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
  // newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
  // newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
  // newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

  let panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
  panGR.delegate = self
  newView.addGestureRecognizer(panGR)
  ```

This code works good.

**Version with constraints:**

```
@IBAction func addView() {
    let newView = CustomView.init()
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    newView.centerXConstraint = newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
    newView.centerYConstraint = newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    newView.centerXConstraint.isActive = true
    newView.centerYConstraint.isActive = true

    let panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    panGR.delegate = self
    newView.addGestureRecognizer(panGR)
}

@objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed,
        let view = gestureRecognizer.view as? CustomView,
        let centerXConstraint = view.centerXConstraint,
        let centerYConstraint = view.centerYConstraint {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        let x = centerXConstraint.constant + translation.x
        let y = centerYConstraint.constant + translation.y
        centerXConstraint.constant = x
        centerYConstraint.constant = y
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
}
```

Add constraint variables in your custom class

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    var centerXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var centerYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

}
```

Comment: Removing the constraints doesn't fix the problem. All the views add and reset in the top left corner.

Comment: Remove height and width constraints as well

Comment: There is one problem though. With a custom view, it doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Do you mean, works with UIImageView, but don't work with your ImageView?
Or you try to add these views to some another view, not self.view?

Comment: It works with UIImageView but not with my custom ImageView.

Comment: I think I figured it out. In my custom view, I used auto layout constraints. Here's what I think is happening: In my view, I used "view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true" but I never set up the custom view using auto layout in my view controller. Does that affect it? And if it does, how do I get around it?